# Heroku not using defined PORT environment var

Tags: node.js, heroku, restify

I made a small app using node.js and Heroku, set the local `.env` file and also used `heroku config:set VARNAME=varValue` to define the port it should listen to both locally and remotely.

```
PROD_MONGODB=mongodb://xxxxxxxxx@dxxxxxxxx:12345/server
PORT=3000
```

I've also checked the app's dashboard on Heroku and I can confirm the vars are set correctly.

Here's the server startup code using restify.

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT, function() {
    console.log('Server listening on port number', process.env.PORT);
});
```

If I run the app locally using `heroku local`, it runs on port 3000 as I expected:

```
Orion:.......$ heroku local
forego | starting web.1 on port 3000
web.1  | 
web.1  | Server listening on port number 3000
```

But when I deploy the app on Heroku, I uses a seemingly random port:

```
2015-09-28T15:15:51.400324+00:00 app[web.1]: Server listening on port number 56680
2015-09-28T15:15:51.486396+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

Is there anything else I can do to make sure Heroku uses the port I defined as an environment variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't define `PORT` - Heroku automatically provides that as part of the environment.

Comment: I didn't understand that part, thank you.

Also, according to this other q&a, Heroku asigns whatever port it wants, but the app is always served on port 80.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706180/setting-the-port-for-node-js-server-on-heroku

Comment: Yes, externally the app will be served on 80 (or 443 for HTTPS). Internally it will listen on the assigned `PORT`.