# How can I deploy a django+swampdragon realtime chatapp on heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, deployment, swampdragon

A simple django chatapp with swampdragon runs perfectly locally. But when I try to deploy it on heroku it shows "Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch" in the log. In the proc file I added "web: python server.py". which runs in the port 9999 locally. But how do I handle the port 9999 with heroku?

Answer (score 1):

See this question:

[Setting the port for node.js server on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706180/setting-the-port-for-node-js-server-on-heroku)

You can't specify which port you want to use on Heroku.

Heroku sets it 'automatically' so you should read what the PORT variable is in the environment then use that.

`heroku config:get PORT`

references: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: I have used the heroku generated port number for my port number and host: gentle-waters-8887.herokuapp.com as my host name in swamp dragon. but it still doesnt work. I think swampdragon cant listen to any port other than 9999 by default. I am having trouble to change swampdragon's default port number 9999. is it correct what I am thinking now?

Comment: check out this: [swamp dragon docs](http://swampdragon.net/documentation/settings/) it shows that there is a setting called 'SWAMP_DRAGON_PORT'. So use your local environment's PORT variable in your apps settings: `SWAMP_DRAGON_PORT = os.environ.get('PORT')` (This variable heroku will automatically assign to you).