# Unity UdpSocketManager and Heroku

Tags: unity-game-engine, heroku

I was testing the server on localhost.

now I wanted to test using Heroku to host the server

but I'm having problems knowing, what would be the correct way to insert the url

before, using localhost

```
 void Start () {
    names = new ArrayList();
    networkPlayers = new ArrayList();

    isActive = true;
    _udpSocketManager = new UdpSocketManager("127.0.0.1", 5000);
    StartCoroutine(_udpSocketManager.initSocket());
    SendPing();

}
```

And now what is the correct procedure to change from 127.0.0.1 to my heroku url is https://wam.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using this [UdpSocketManager](https://github.com/M-Aghasi/Unity-UdpSocket-BitStream-Utilities/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/UdpSocket_BitStream_Utilities/UdpSocketManager.cs). If so it uses [UdpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient(v=vs.110).aspx), which means you can just use `wam.herokuapp.com` as the server address.

However, when deploying your server on heroku, be sure to check your [port configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706180/setting-the-port-for-node-js-server-on-heroku).