# Why I can't connect to my websocket server deployed to Heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, websocket

Before it was working perfectly on my VPS, but I decided to try Heroku.
I successfully deployed by app there, but could not connect to it...
Why could it happen? Is there any port setting in Heroku or something?

[image]

Comment: Did you use your own presets port ? or port defined by heroku in process.env.PORT ?

Comment: Can you share the code please

Comment: @Robert own port... Do I need to use process.env.PORT instead? But how to share that port with my client for that server?

Comment: heroku don't allow to use own port configuration. you have to use this one which heroku expose. try to use there port and connect without passing any in connection string (works for me)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706180/setting-the-port-for-node-js-server-on-heroku