# Node.js in Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I am hosting my very simple nodejs server in Heroku. But, when I try it, it returns this error:

> Application error
> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application
> owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command`

Here's the `server.js`:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 80;

const server = express();

server.use(cors());

server.get("/", (req, res) => {
  const INDEX = "/index.html";
  res.sendFile(INDEX, { root: __dirname });
});

server.get("/test", (req, res) => {
  res.send("test Page");
});

server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`listening on port ${PORT}`));
```

package.json:

```
{
"name": "express-heroku",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "15.11.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

Don't know what the reason is, but, when I try this in the `localhost` it works perfectly!

The *full* error on Heroku CLI:
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated !

Comment: Like it says, check the logs for more details. It'll be hard to debug without an error message.

Comment: Here's what I got from the Heroku console -> `2021-03-10T15:48:28.602246+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=creativity-server.herokuapp.com request_id=bb9535df-ae21-4198-88bc-8ba20c5d092d fwd="157.44.142.5" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-03-10T15:48:29.303442+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=creativity-server.herokuapp.com request_id=5f7a1b87-0fb7-42a0-a04a-3aab5d7b94a4 fwd="157.44.142.5" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`

Comment: Hers's the image -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgxJk.png

Comment: did you set up correctly the environment variables?

Comment: Did you mean the `process.env.PORT` ?  I thought that it was already defined by Heroku itself !

Comment: yes, but  you have to declare `PORT` with no value on _config vars_ page.

Comment: I found that there is no need for declaring `PORT` https://stackoverflow.com/a/52806264/14942924

Comment: Could you find the updated code  in the question

Comment: Please post you package.json

Comment: Are you able to scroll up in the error log? The original reason/error might be logged earlier/above the parts you've shared.

Comment: Oh God ! Why I didn't notice that before ?
The error was in the `package.json` ! There was no mention of `cors` in the dependencies list. That's why the app crashed !
Thanks everyone !

Answer (score 0):

Create a ProcFile:
[image]

Inside the ProcFile add `web: node index.js`[image]

Doing this, you are telling heroku to run your server, with node.

Comment: Thanks ! But unfortunately, it doesn't work !