# Heroku + Node.js: Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, deployment, web-deployment

I built a Node.js/Express Web Api. I want to deploy it on Heroku. It works fine on local but when I deploy it I get the following error:

```
 Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

`index.js`

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
    console.log(`app running on ${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

`.env`

```
PORT=3000
```

I have configured the **PORT** variable on Heroku -> Settings ->Config Vars section. However it didn't solve my problem.

Additionally, when I look up the application logs on Heroku, the callback function on the listen() method, outputs the following:

```
2022-07-15T20:06:19.268954+00:00 app[web.1]: app running on undefined 
2022-07-15T20:06:20.230943+00:00 app[web.1]: connected to db
```

`connected to db` output came from mongodb connection. My app also gets the mongodb credentials from .env file and it works fine. But why I can't get **PORT** variable and it returns `undefined`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706180/setting-the-port-for-node-js-server-on-heroku) and the answer is - `PORT` variable is provided by Heroku and you can't set it.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the **PORT** variable either on .env file or Config Vars on Heroku.
And I change the way to call the PORT variable to not conflict with Heroku's default **PORT**.

`index.js`

```
let port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`app running on ${port} `);
});
```

App runs on 3000 port in localhost and Heroku's default port in server now.